# DynamoDb get item the number of conditions on the keys is invalid

Tags: node.js, amazon-dynamodb

I've been trying to find an explanation for this situation but I didn't find any.
I have two DynamoDb tables, both with two key indexes, one is a HASH key and the other is a RANGE key.

In the table where both keys are strings, I can query the database with just the HASH key like this (using the node sdk):

```js
  const params = {
    TableName: process.env.DYNAMODB_TABLE,
    Key: { id: sessionId },
  };
  const { Item } = await dynamoDb.get(params);
```

However, the same operation on the other table throws the mentioned error about `The number of conditions on the keys is invalid`

Here are the two table schemas:

This table definiton allows me to use the mentioned query.

```
  SessionsDynamoDbTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    DeletionPolicy: Retain
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: userId
          AttributeType: S
        -
          AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        -
          AttributeName: startDate
          AttributeType: S
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: userId
          KeyType: HASH
        -
          AttributeName: id
          KeyType: RANGE
      LocalSecondaryIndexes:
        - IndexName: byDate
          KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: userId
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: startDate
            KeyType: RANGE
          Projection:
            NonKeyAttributes:
            - endDate
            - name
            ProjectionType: INCLUDE
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

This does not allow me to make a query like the one mentioned

```
  SessionsTable:
    Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
    TimeToLiveDescription:
      AttributeName: expiresAt
      Enabled: true
    Properties:
      AttributeDefinitions:
        -
          AttributeName: id
          AttributeType: S
        -
          AttributeName: expiresAt
          AttributeType: N
      KeySchema:
        -
          AttributeName: id
          KeyType: HASH
        -
          AttributeName: expiresAt
          KeyType: RANGE
      BillingMode: PAY_PER_REQUEST
      TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

I'm including the entire table definition because I don't know if secondary indexes can have an impact or not on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> You must provide the name of the partition key attribute and a single value for that attribute. Query returns all items with that partition key value. Optionally, you can provide a sort key attribute and use a comparison operator to refine the search results.[more](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html)
>
> **get**(params, callback) ⇒ AWS.Request 
>   Returns a set of attributes for the item with the given **primary key** by delegating to AWS.DynamoDB.getItem().

In SessionsTable `id` is HASH key and in SessionsDynamoDbTable `id` in RANGE key.for SessionsDynamoDbTable  you should provide HASH Key in addition to RANGE 
 key.

Comment: Do you mean that you can search by range key without including the entire key, but if you search by HASH key you must include the entire key?

Comment: you can search by hash key, and please have look at your tables, it seems the order not true. your sample query work with the second table(SessionsTable)

Comment: you can search by Hash key without including the entire key, but if you search by Rang key you must include the entire key.(hash key)

Comment: I updated my example to make it clear, but my experience is exactly the opposite you mentioned. I can make a query including only the range key and not the hash key

Comment: Please have look https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Query.html

Comment: Please note that I am using get item, not a query. However, the official documentation says exactly the same as you wrote:  "With GetItem, you must specify the entire primary key, not just part of it. For example, if a table has a composite primary key (partition key and sort key), you must supply a value for the partition key and a value for the sort key".